# JSP including page using parameters

Tags: jsp, dynamic, include

My problem is simple, so should the solution. :P

I'm have two files.

Index.jsp

```
<%  
String title = "Homepage";
String desc  = "...'";
String root  = ".";
String include = "content-index.jsp";
%>
<%@ include file="layout.jsp"%>
```

And my layout.jsp

```
...
<jsp:include page="{include}"/>
...
```

I want to use the content from the parameter index.jsp.include into the include statement in this file.
This doesn't give me any error message, but it also returns a empty block where the page content should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think this should work? Curly braces don't have any special meaning in JSPs.

You just need `<jsp:include page="<%= include %>"/>`.

Also, you should avoid scriptlets and use the JSP EL and the JSTL:

```
<c:set var="title" value="Homepage"/>
<c:set var="include" value="content-index.jsp"/>

<jsp:include page="${include}"/>
```

Comment: Well after struggling with this for a while I see that
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Tag Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <c:set var="salary" value="${2000*2}"/>
    <c:out value="${salary}"/>
    </body>
    </html>
gives me memory overflow, and endless loops